# Calculate the volume bounded by $z = 0$, $z = y^2$, $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Calculate the volume of the solid bounded by these surfaces:

$z = 0$,
$z = y^2$,
$x^2+y^2=1$

I visualized the surfaces and came to a conclusion of this integral:

$\iint{dxdy}\int_{0}^{y^2}dz$

After calculating it and swapping to $x=r \cos {\theta}$, $x=r \sin {\theta}$, I finished with the result of $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Is this the correct way of calculating the result of this exercise and did I arrive at the correct conclusion at the end?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What does $\iint\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\int_0^{y^2}\,\mathrm dz$ mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos that's the notation we use at our university, I think it would generally also be ($\iint(\int_{0}^{y^2}dz)dxdy$)

Comment: And the first two integrals go from where to where?

Comment: Well after switching to polar coordinates the $r$ goes from 0 to 1 and $\theta$ from 0 to $2\pi$

Comment: You did not write that in your post. And if you switch to polar coordinates, then there should no $y$ anymore.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have no idea whether it's correct but in polar coordinates the integral becomes $\iint r^3\sin^2{\theta}drd\theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you express your region in cylindrical coordinates, then $x^2+y^2=1$ becomes $\rho=1$ and $z=y^2$ becomes $z=\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)$. So, you can compute your volume as follows:\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)}\rho\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\rho^3\sin^2(\theta)\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta\right)\left(\int_0^1\rho^3\,\mathrm d\rho\right)\\&=\frac\pi4.\end{align}

Comment: Okay that would seem correct as it's the same result as with polar coordinates, I just made a small mistake and I didn't multiply by the jacobian when switching to a different coordinate system. Thank you, this is correct.